# uses of jacobian matrix

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative

I need to find uses and interesting questions by using jacobian matrix for a project work               ,can any one help me. I found jacobian matrix is used in dynamical systems, but i didn't understand it.Is there is any question in dynamical systems which is connected to jacobian matrix

Comment: The most basic thing is that if $f:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ is differentiable at $x$, and we know the value of $f$ at $x$, then we can estimate the value of $f$ at a nearby point $x + \Delta x$ using $f(x + \Delta x) \approx f(x) + f'(x) \Delta x$, where $f'(x)$ is the Jacobian of $f$ at $x$.

Comment: Yes. Linearising nonlinear dynamical systems about a stationary point (i.e. evaluating the Jacobian at that point) gives some indication of the sort of behaviour we may expect at that point.

Comment: tnxx for answer